# Mongoose add or update values in an array inside an object inside an array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema, upsert, subquery

This is my schema,

```
const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  code: String,
  class: String,
  credit: Number,
  overview: String,
  prerequisite: String,
  syllabus: [
    {
      moduleName: String,
      moduleDetails: String,
    },
  ],
  materials: [
    {
      moduleNo: Number,
      moduleMaterials: [String],
    },
  ],
  teacher: String,
  students: [String],
});
```

I want to add new materials in which each time an update operation is called I receive a
**moduleNo** and a **materialURL**.
I want to add this to the **materials** array in my existing course which is filtered by **courseID**. So each time I receive a **moduleNo** and a **materialURL**, I want to check if **moduleNo** already exists in the materials array. If yes, then add **materialURL** into the **moduleMaterials** array without deleting the existing urls in **moduleMaterials**. If no, then add a new object with **moduleNo** and **moduleMaterials** and **materialURL** pushed into **moduleMaterials**. I've heard about upsert and think that could be used but I'm not sure what the correct queries are to do this operation.
What I've currently come up with even though it's wrong,

```
  Course.updateOne(
    { _id: courseID },
    {
      $push: {
        materials: { moduleNo, moduleMaterials: { $push: { materialURL } } },
      },
    },
    { upsert: true },
    (err, result) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err);
      } else {
        console.log(result);
      }
    }
  );
```

How do I do execute this query?